# Chrome not allowing Ajax request to permitted domains

Tags: javascript, ajax, security, google-chrome-extension, xss

I'm creating my first Chrome extension, a relatively simple one with some ajax calls.

My manifest is pretty simple:

```
{
    "name": "Read It Now",
    "version": "0.12",
    "description": "Read it now.",
    "permissions": [
                    "https://readitlaterlist.com"
                   ],
  "app": {
      "launch": {
          "local_path": "index.html"
      }
  }
}
```

I'm then using jQuery to fetch some simple data from a URL like:

```
https://readitlaterlist.com/v2/get?state=unread&count=10&apikey=xxx&username=yyy&password=zzz
```

However, Chrome still rejects it:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   https://readitlaterlist.com/v2/get?state=unread&count=10&apikey=xxx&username=yyy&password=zzz.
>   Origin chrome-extension://cdfeahailioembamnjnikbiemengfgpp is not
>   allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to include the path in your [URL match pattern](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/match_patterns.html). `"https://readitlaterlist.com/*"` should fix your problem.

Comment: Close - turns out I needed the ending slash. 'https://readitlaterlist.com/' (sans '*') actually does the trick.  Thanks for sending me down the right path.