# Chrome browser is possible to re-launch an ajax request

Tags: ajax, google-chrome

Is it possible to re-launch an **ajax request** after it was launched for the first time?

Can't find out how to **re-launch** it. I have  the old one in the network tab, but as I see I can't repeat it.

Comment: check this question mate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8876442/chrome-not-allowing-ajax-request-to-permitted-domains

Comment: @vignesh4303: How is that relevant?

Comment: omg i voted up for nothing sorry that link has nothing related to my question, i'm talking about the chrome instruments!!